# Error getting CLLocationCorrdinate2D from Cllocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am trying to get a CLLocationCoordinate2D from a CLLocation object. I am using the following code, which is called through an NSNotification:

```
-(void)setMapCenterWith:(CLLocation*)location {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = location.coordinate;
    [self moveToCoordinate:coord];
}
```

I have verified that the location object being passed in is valid and contains a location. However, when the line containing `location.coordinate` is called, the app crashes with the following error:

```
[NSConcreteNotification coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here is the log output on the location object:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x798988e0 {name = PPTFormSubmittedWithLocation; object = <+38.05230000,-81.10880000> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 3/22/15, 12:35:34 PM Eastern Daylight Time}
```

Any idea why this is happneing? Thanks!

Comment: Can you `NSLog` location please?  And post the full error?

Comment: Sure, see edits to my question

Comment: `location` is an `NSNotification`, not a `CLLocation`.  Can you `NSLog` `location.userInfo`?

Comment: userInfo is nil. So the issue lies in the way I am sending a notification? It kinda doesn't make sense since the location object does contain the location?

Comment: What about `location.object`?

Comment: looks like I just needed to work from location.object. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setMapCenterWith` is called by an `NSNotificationCenter`, which means it needs to take an `NSNotification` as it's parameter:

```
-(void)setMapCenterWith:(NSNotification *)notif
```

It looks like the notification's object is the `CLLocation` you are interested in, so you need to change your method to this:

```
-(void)setMapCenterWith:(NSNotification *)notif {
    CLLocation *location = notif.object;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = location.coordinate;
    [self moveToCoordinate:coord];
}
```